# cocoa-touch: Why is font not applied?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uifont

I'm trying to code the appearance of an UILabel, but I can't get another font applied. The funny (or rather annoying) thing is that if I add a second UILabel, the font WILL BE APPLIED for the second label, BUT NOT the first. I'm slightly going crazy on this... especially the font size won't change if I try to.

My code (found in my ViewDidLoad):

```
    NSString* dateWeekDay = @"MON";
CGRect dateWeekDayFrame = CGRectMake(183, 12, 34, 21);
viewNoteDateWeekDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dateWeekDayFrame];
viewNoteDateWeekDay.text = dateWeekDay;
viewNoteDateWeekDay.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
viewNoteTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:70.0f]; // I know this size is crazy, but it's just to show that it has no effect whatsoever...
viewNoteDateWeekDay.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( -90 * M_PI ) / 180 );
viewNoteDateWeekDay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSString* dateDay = @"01";
CGRect dateDayFrame = CGRectMake(209, 3, 47, 50);
viewNoteDateDay = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dateDayFrame];
viewNoteDateDay.text = dateDay;
viewNoteDateDay.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
viewNoteDateDay.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:33.0f];
viewNoteDateDay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSString* dateMonth = @"SEPTEMBER";
CGRect dateMonthFrame = CGRectMake(249, 6, 93, 31);
viewNoteDateMonth = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dateMonthFrame];
viewNoteDateMonth.text = dateMonth;
viewNoteDateMonth.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
viewNoteDateMonth.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0f];
viewNoteDateMonth.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying the wrong variable name when you're setting the font property. Your code says: `viewNoteTitle.font = ...` when it should read `viewNoteDateWeekDay.font = ...`

Comment: Thanks... sometimes you simply can't think straight forward anymore. Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure. Getting a second set of eyes always helps.